# Files on SSD disappear, reappear after restarting

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1, ntfs

After not using my PC for a while, all of the files on the non-system `D:\` drive disappear. It doesn't happen on the system drive (SSD) or another data drive (HDD). I'm not sure if this only happens after going to sleep. The files and directories in the root are still visible, but looking in any directory will show it to be completely empty. Trying to look in a file, shows that it doesn't exist.

[image]
*Image 1: Looking at the drive in Explorer, I can see the root directory listing.*

[image]
*Image 2: Trying to open the file in the root, shows this.*

[image]
*Image 3: After a restart though, everything returns, intact*.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is the `D:` drive shared over the network? That particular file is marked as "Available offline." What happens if you manually put the system to sleep, and wake it up later on?

Comment: The file is offline because the disk is being powered off more then likely because its configured to do so.  Use Device Manager to change this behavior.

Comment: @and31415 No, it's local. Files on my system drive have that Availability text as well.

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm, something is weird. There are no changeable settings in DM, and there isn't even a Policies tab. I'm going to try setting keep my hard drives from sleeping for now.

Comment: Properties on the device itself within Device Manager.  There is not setting that determines if the device should be turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from OCZ:

> The series 2 model drive is not compatible with Haswell based
>   chipsets. It will not function correctly or even at all if attached to
>   the Haswell Intel SATA ports on the motherboard.
>
> If your motherboard has an onboard integrated raid controller, such as
>   one made by Marvell, ASMedia, or JMicron the drive will work fine in
>   one of these SATA ports. But it will not function correctly when
>   attached to an Intel SATA port on a Haswell motherboard.